# check if any of element has a text - without each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to `return false` if any of `mdpoptags` has text as variable `a`.
I want do this without `each` loop.

```js
var a = 'ABBA'
if ($('.mdpoptag:contains(' + a + ')').length > 0) {
  console.log('323');
  //return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='mdpoptag'>ABBA</div>
<div class='mdpoptag'>ABB</div>
<div class='mdpoptag'>AB</div>
```

Problem: if `a` is `ABB` or `AB` - result is true.

I need to match the entire `a` string with entire `mdpoptags` text.

Is it possible using `contains`, or `include`... just without `each` loop?

Comment: [use a filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

Comment: I'm sure jQuery *does* use a loop internally to implement `contains` - why not use one yourself?

Comment: Use `filter()` to get an exact match, however you should still note that jQuery is looping through the elements internally (as there's no other way to do this), so the 'no loop' requirement is rather odd

Comment: How to set `filter`  - `criteria` argument in the above case, pls

Comment: @puerto Your code works properly. There is no div with string `ABBA;` There is a div with string `ABBA` though. You have a typo.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski, thanks, I correct this.

Comment: @puerto if now it is not what you wanted, then what would you like to achieve?

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski, I want to `return false` if any of `mdpoptag` has text identical to var `a`, without using `each` loop.

Comment: @puerto And that's exactly what is happening in your example.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski, please check, console is written if `a` = `ABB` for example

Comment: @puerto I did and it works the same way.

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski, what is `the same way`? Did you get `323` in console if `a` is `ABB` ?

Comment: @puerto Yes that's what I meant

Comment: @KrzysztofJaniszewski, but I need that ONLY if a div contains complete `ABBA`, not `ABB` or `AB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added some other examples to make it more generic.
Let's say the action you want to execute on all your matched elements is `.hide()`, to make it simple.

Snippet using `:contains()`:

```js
var a = 'ABBA';

// If you want to execute a global action on all your elements, you can do the following:
var matched = $('.mdpoptag:contains(' + a + ')');
if (matched.length) {
  matched.hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='mdpoptag'>ABBA</div><!-- ABBA is here -->
<div class='mdpoptag'>ABB</div>
<div class='mdpoptag'>AB</div>
<div class='mdpoptag'>ABBABB</div>
<div class='mdpoptag'>BBABBA</div>
<div class='mdpoptag'>ABBA</div><!-- ABBA is here too -->
```

The problem here is that `:contains()` matches "ABBABB" and "BBABBA" too.

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

So, you may want to use `.filter()` instead:

```js
var a = 'ABBA';
var matched = $('.mdpoptag').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === a;
});
if (matched.length) {
  matched.hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='mdpoptag'>ABBA</div><!-- ABBA is here! -->
<div class='mdpoptag'>ABB</div>
<div class='mdpoptag'>AB</div>
<div class='mdpoptag'>ABBABB</div>
<div class='mdpoptag'>BBABBA</div>
<div class='mdpoptag'>ABBA</div><!-- ABBA is here too -->
```

Documentation about `.filter()`: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

Also, note that if you want to `console()` something **for each** element, a loop is mandatory.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me to find the final sollution.

Comment: @puerto Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing now becuase in my opinion the answer to your question is already in your question.

If you want to display only those divs that does not contain variable `a` value then you can do it like this

```js
var a = 'ABBA',
  container = $('.mdpoptag:contains(' + a + ')');
  
if (container.length > 0) {
  container.hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='mdpoptag'>ABBA</div>
<div class='mdpoptag'>ABB</div>
<div class='mdpoptag'>AB</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a spelling error in your variable a content.

```js
var a = 'ABBA';
if ($('.mdpoptag:contains(' + a + ')').length > 0) {
  console.log('found!');
  //return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='mdpoptag'>ABBA</div>
<div class='mdpoptag'>ABB</div>
<div class='mdpoptag'>AB</div>
```